# Implementing OnClickListener for dynamically created ExpandableListView with item having Radiobuttons in Android

Tags: android

when on radio button of one heading is checked then other radio buttons are also getting checked by their own. and on expanding all and swiping the screen the radio button title is getting exchanged or shifted.
please help how to manage dynamically made form with many radiobutton options. in my case the form is in expandable list view.Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener{
    public Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;
    private List<Services> cpvalue;
    private List<Options> options;
    //private boolean[] flag;
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap,List<Services> cpvalue) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
        this.cpvalue=cpvalue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle=(String)getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText=(String)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            options=cpvalue.get(groupPosition).getCheckPoints().get(childPosition).getCp_options();
            /*flag=new boolean[options.size()];
            for(int f=1;f<options.size();f++) {
                flag[f]=false;
            }*/
            for (int k = 0; k < options.size(); k++) {
                View radioButtonView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.check_radio_button, null);
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioButtonView
                        .findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
                //radioButton.setId(options.get(k).getId());
                radioButton.setText(options.get(k).getCp_value());
               radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(getOnCheckDoSomething(radioButton));
               // radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView);

            }
            /*radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                    Toast.makeText(context, "okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/
        }
        TextView txtListChild=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }




    RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener getOnCheckDoSomething(final RadioButton button)  {
        return new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.d("hello" , "hogaya");
                Toast.makeText(context, "okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because creation of radio buttons is problematic. If I would create radio buttons dynamically I would do it somewhat like following,

```
final RadioButton[] rb;
//You can create a new radio group    
//RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this.context); //create the RadioGroup
// Or use from your xml
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for(int i=0; i < options.size(); i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this.context);
        radioGroup.addView(rb[i]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup
        rb[i].setText(options.get(k).getCp_value());
    }
// if you added new radio group    
//convertView.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout, I suppose convertView is a layout view

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                Toast.makeText(context, "okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```